# Shortest distance for cuboid by taking a certain path in 3D

Tags: 3d, pythagorean-triples

[image]

I am stuck on part (b) of the question. Please see image above.
How would I work out the shortest distance with reducing the amount of cheese the ant has to crawl through?

Comment: I really don't understand part a).  As to part b) see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189743/minimum-distance-to-reach-opposite-corner

Comment: @saulspatz It's easy to understand. Its favorite food is cheese; so it should travel **through** the cheese (eating cheese on its way); hence the shortest distance is the diagonal of the cube: $d^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$. For part b, it's stated that she hates cheese; so she should walk on the cheese.

Comment: @EtackSxchange Thank you.

Comment: @saulspatz You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you for the very quick replies. I'm still stuck sadly. Been working through the  Minimum distance to reach opposite corner – @cosmo5 . The answer is meant to be 50 for part b) but cannot get it. I'm getting d^2 = (30+20)^2 +20^2 (making the net of the cube from there look like that of a cuboid with the dimension from the question)....

Comment: @pythag1 $\sqrt{(30+20)^2 +20^2}=10\sqrt{29}$ should be correct according to given diagram. Given answer $50$ seems wrong.

Comment: @pythag1 Have you checked my answer? I get nearly 50 for part b)  in two ways.

Answer (score 0):

The Pythagorean theorem works in unlimited dimensions so, if she love cheese and would eat her way through, the distance $$d=\sqrt{20^2+20^2+30^2}=\sqrt{1700}\approx 41.23$$

If she hates cheese, the way along the edges is $d=20+20+30=70$

OTOH, if she walks half-way down a 20-side while walking horizontally the other full 20-side, she can the continue the rest of the way down the 20-side while walking the full length of the 30-side.

$$\sqrt{20^2+10^2}+\sqrt{10^2+30^2}=\sqrt{500}+\sqrt{1000}\approx
22.36 + 31.62\approx 53.98$$

Another way is to think of the 20X30 and a 20X20 sections as a single rectangle.

$$\sqrt{(30+20)^2+20^2}=\sqrt{2900}\approx 53.85$$